# textract failed with exit code 127: pdftotext on windows 10

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, pypdf, pdftotext

I am trying to run a python program on a windows 10 machine with which I am trying to read and convert PDF files. However every time I run the program I get the following error. I have not found out how to resolve this yet. Is there anyone who can help me please :)

```html
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trpfinance\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\textract\parsers\utils.py", line 82, in run
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\Users\trpfinance\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\trpfinance\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trpfinance\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "EinkaufRGWindows.py", line 40, in InkoopRekeningen
    text = textract.process(str(importfolder) + str(i))
  File "C:\Users\trpfinance\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\textract\parsers\__init__.py", line 77, in process
    return parser.process(filename, encoding, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trpfinance\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\textract\parsers\utils.py", line 46, in process
    byte_string = self.extract(filename, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trpfinance\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\textract\parsers\pdf_parser.py", line 28, in extract
    raise ex
  File "C:\Users\trpfinance\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\textract\parsers\pdf_parser.py", line 20, in extract
    return self.extract_pdftotext(filename, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trpfinance\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\textract\parsers\pdf_parser.py", line 43, in extract_pdftotext
    stdout, _ = self.run(args)
  File "C:\Users\trpfinance\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\textract\parsers\utils.py", line 90, in run
    raise exceptions.ShellError(
textract.exceptions.ShellError: The command `pdftotext //Mac/Home/Desktop/Wickey Einkauf Test/Rekeningen/Lekkerkerker_ - 20803471.pdf -` failed with exit code 127
------------- stdout -------------
------------- stderr -------------
```

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory: **The system cannot find the file specified**

Comment: @BryanOakley It would seem self-explanatory however I wouldn't know what file exactly I'm missing, where to place it or what to install to get to that file

Comment: The missing program is `pdftotext.exe` which is part of [`Poppler`](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/).  However latest `poppler` release does not include binaries for Windows, but you can use the package released in [`msys2`](https://www.msys2.org/) or [poppler-windows](http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/).

Comment: @acw1668 I managed to find pdftotext.exe (also referenced in textract documentation) using after downloading poppler 23.08 as opposed to poppler 23.09. Once I have pdfoftext.exe, however, what do I need to do (ie where exactly do I use it?)

Comment: @acw1668 Could you please provide an example to a newbie? Thanks